# Is it possible to have if else/if in a ternary operator on ngClass?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, conditional-operator

Example would be something like:

```
[ngClass]="condition1 ? 'class1' : condition2 ? 'class2' : ''"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *now*.  For the first few years of Angular 1.0 (now AngularJS) that idiom was not supported, and there may be old documentation still floating around that references that shortcoming.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have if else/if in a ternary operator on ngClass?

Yes. Your example should work.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine. Already tested and used in Angular 8.

```
[ngClass]="condition1 ? 'class1' : condition2 ? 'class2' : ''"
```